# How can I repaint a bad paint job?

Tags: wood, exterior, repainting

I just got a wooden sweet cart made for myself.  I asked someone to paint it for me but he did a really bad job. He didn't let paint dry completely so it has smudged all over an looks uneven. How can I go about repainting it myself? The cart is made out of pine. What process and products should I use?

Comment: Kind of a vague question. I suggest doing more research so you can ask a more specific question and have a clearer idea of what you are doing before coming here.

Answer (score 4):

The basic process I would use is

1. Find out what type of paint was used (both primer and top-coat) so that I can obtain and apply a compatible paint. If I couldn't find out, I'd try overpainting a small area in an inconspicuous position and see what happens.
2. Sand it flat using increasingly fine grades of sandpaper, then clean it.
3. Buy new paint and carefully follow the instructions on the tin. Make sure to use primer first if there are any areas of bare wood.

Worst case is probably buy paint stripper and clean it back to bare wood.